# Kotlin: Funtional Type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting below error while compiling:

**Type mismatch: inferred type is (String, Boolean) -> Any but ((String, Boolean) -> Unit)?  was expected**

*My Type Declaration is*

```
private val ConsisFilter_Click = { filterText: String, isStrictSearch: Boolean ->

    try {
        //My Codes
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        try {
            alert{}.show()
        }catch (ignored: Exception) {}
    }
}



var ConsisFilterClickEvent:((filterText: String, isStrictSearch: Boolean) -> Unit)? = null
```

*assigninkg like this*

```
inputDialog!!.ConsisFilterClickEvent = ConsisFilter_Click
```

I'm following same pattern elsewhere but not getting any error. Only this particular piece is giving problem. Am I doing something wrong. Please help me.

**NOTE:** If I put all codes of `ConsisFilter_Click` (code of try catch block) into a separate function and simply call that function from `ConsisFilter_Click` then every this works well

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't assign `ConsisFilter_Click` to the variable `ConsisFilterClickEvent` since its implicit type is `(String, Boolean) -> Any` rather than `(String, Boolean) -> Unit`. due to the return type of the **catch-block** is `Unit` but the return type of the last statement of the **try-block** is not `Unit` , that will makes the lambda's return type to `Any` if you don't using an explicit type variable.

you must define the type of the variable `ConsisFilter_Click` explicitly as below:

```
val ConsisFilter_Click: (filterText: String, isStrictSearch: Boolean) -> Unit  = {
    filterText: String, isStrictSearch: Boolean ->

    try {
        //My Codes
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        try {
            alert{}.show()
        }catch (ignored: Exception) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When using a lambda in Kotlin, if the inferred return type is not `Unit`, [the last expression in it is returned](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax). In your case, this is the try-catch statement, which also works [as an expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#try-is-an-expression) in Kotlin.

If you want to force your lambda's return type to be `Unit`, you can either write down its type explicitly as stated in the other answer, or you can directly assign it to `ConsisFilterClickEvent` instead of storing it in another variable first - in both of these cases, the compiler will figure out that you don't want to return your last expression, and just want to use try-catch as a statement.

Another thing you can do is to explicitly return the `Unit` object at the end of your lambda:

```
private val ConsisFilter_Click = { filterText: String, isStrictSearch: Boolean ->
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        ...
    }
    Unit
}
```